# get warning when running apps

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle

Help me please.
I get a warning like this when installing a project on my cellphone

> w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:

I have already updated Kotlin.
Now I use kotlin version 1.3.70 stable
I use Android Studio version 3.5.1
I use gradle version 5.4.1
this is my gradle on app level

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lumbunginovasi.ludesid"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        versionNameSuffix 'default'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions 'version'
    productFlavors {
        cs10 {
            dimension 'version'
            minSdkVersion 19
            applicationId "com.lumbunginovasi.kepengbenang.pos"
            versionNameSuffix 'pos_cs10'
        }

        base {
            dimension 'version'
            minSdkVersion 16
            applicationId "com.lumbunginovasi.ludesid"
            versionNameSuffix 'base'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation androidXDeps.appCompat
    implementation androidXDeps.constraintlayout
    implementation androidXDeps.material
    implementation coroutineDeps.retrofit
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha01'
    implementation coroutineDeps.core
    implementation coroutineDeps.android
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.6.1'
    implementation project(':ludes_kasir')
    implementation project(':ludes_ui')
    implementation project(':ludes_core')
    implementation project(path: ':ludes_products')
    implementation project(path: ':ludes_api')
    implementation project(path: ':ludes_sugarORM')
    implementation project(path: ':ludes_account')
    implementation project(path: ':bluetoothprinter')
    implementation 'com.asksira.android:bsimagepicker:1.2.2'
    cs10Implementation project(path: ':pos_cs10')
    implementation project(path: ':internetservice')
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation project(path: ':sync_transaction')
}
```

thank you